# How do you create a library of shapes for PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, shapes

How do you make your own shapes that can be used like the stock PowerPoint shapes?  Here is an example,

[image]

See the PowerMockup Shapes?  How do you create that kind of library?  It doesn't seem it is the usual Custom Shapes tutorial type library you find in a search.  These, and the built in ones like StoryBuilder seem to be a different *kind* altogether.

This did not help,
[How to create a custom "Shapes" menu in Powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/719955/how-to-create-a-custom-shapes-menu-in-powerpoint)
[Precision custom shapes in PowerPoint](https://superuser.com/questions/623461/precision-custom-shapes-in-powerpoint)

EDIT:  What I mean by a different kind is these do not look like they were made by using stock PP squares and circles morphed into an Infographic.  They're different looking.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows PowerMockup, which is a commercial 3rd party add-in. It contains a set of objects that have a "hand-drawn" look, commonly used in storyboarding or wireframing. The hand-drawn look is part of the add-in, not part of PowerPoint.

In order to create similar looking shapes, you would have to use the drawing tools with the free form or pencil, not the square and circles. Good luck with that.

Comment: After research, I believe I need to use something like Inkscape or Illustrator and save them as .emf files that can then be used in PowerPoint.